# Can I apply an image transformation to an arbitrary image (non-Assets field)?

Tags: templating

Curious if I'm able to use the resizer on a random, sourced image, not coming from a field anywhere.

So I would just be passing a string to the path of the image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While *transforms* are an asset-only feature, you can get at all of the underlying image manipulation features pretty easily using the ImagesService.

```
$image = craft()->images->loadImage($imageSource);
$image->setQuality($quality);
$image->resize($transform->width, $transform->height);
$image->saveAs($targetFile);
```

Comment: and that pretty much sums up why i love craft!!

Comment: Lovely! Looks like I just need a quick plugin to do this from Twig.

Comment: Any pointers on how I could get the two other transform parameters to work? `mode` and `position`

Comment: @peirix Not sure I’m following - probably worth posting as a new question.

Comment: @BrandonKelly I actually figured it out. What I was after was a way to send in `width`, `height`, `quality`, `mode` and `position`, like I would do with a regular assets transform. But I found that the `$image` will have both `scaleAndCrop` (which will take `position`) and `scaleToFit`.

Answer (score 3):

No.

A transform can only be applied to an [AssetFileModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/assetfilemodel), and there is no AssetFileModel for a random image.